# What to do when the connection times out when using TOR browser?

Tags: networking, browser, connection, tor, darknet

So I downloaded TOR and when trying to view sites, the connection keeps getting timed out.This only happens on TOR and not chrome or firefox.
Additionally, I tried abling javascript,disabling my antivirus,making sure the time was accurate,removing the padlock/s in the url,using  DNS server IP address and an alternative one but the connection still keeps getting timed out.Does anyone know what can I do to actually view the site?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean saying "the connection keeps getting timed out"? Do you mean web pages do not open or the connection of your device gets timed out? Do you use proxy server? The problem comes up when you try to connect to the usual sites or TOR links?

Comment: Actually it was due to my antivirus software now that I see it.When I replaced it with another one, it works alright.There are still some sites that show this and they probably are out of order/old ones.